# executing a command of a chroot outside of the chroot

Tags: linux, chroot

I have a chroot environment on `/data/workbench/mnt` and I want to execute a binary which is inside the chroot environment (for example `/data/workbench/mnt/bin/bash`). I added the chroot library path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and I just did `/data/workbench/mnt/bin/bash`. I get a very strange error: `No such file or directory`. I am ABSOLUTELY sure that the file exists. When I `chroot /data/workbench/mnt /bin/bash` everything runs smoothly without errors. What's going on?

BTW: I'm on armv7l

Comment: Yes, I know you said “I am ABSOLUTELY sure that the file exists.”  But is it possible that the command you’re running (which you say, for example, is `/bin/bash` in the “chroot environment”) is a symbolic link to an absolute pathname that’s rooted in the chroot environment (and which does not have a counterpart in the outside environment)?  Or that one of its dynamic libraries is?

Comment: it's not. no command works. and isn't linking anywhere is it? I get no errors about the libs...